# nth weekday calculation in Python - whats wrong with this code?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the nth weekday for a given date. For example, I should be able to calculate the 3rd wednesday in the month for a given date.

I have written 2 versions of a function that is supposed to do that:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

### version 1
def nth_weekday(the_date, nth_week, week_day):
    temp = the_date.replace(day=1)
    adj = (nth_week-1)*7 + temp.weekday()-week_day
    return temp + timedelta(days=adj)

### version 2
def nth_weekday(the_date, nth_week, week_day):
    temp = the_date.replace(day=1)
    adj = temp.weekday()-week_day
    temp += timedelta(days=adj)
    temp += timedelta(weeks=nth_week)
    return temp
```

**Console output**

```
# Calculate the 3rd Friday for the date 2011-08-09
x=nth_weekday(datetime(year=2011,month=8,day=9),3,4)
print 'output:',x.strftime('%d%b%y') 

# output: 11Aug11 (Expected: '19Aug11')
```

The logic in both functions is obviously wrong, but I can't seem to locate the bug - can anyone spot what is wrong with the code - and how do I fix it to return the correct value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
adj = temp.weekday()-week_day
```

First of all, you are subtracting things the wrong way: you need to subtract the actual day from the desired one, not the other way around.

Second, you need to ensure that the result of the subtraction is not negative - it should be put in the range 0-6 using `% 7`.

The result:

```
adj = (week_day - temp.weekday()) % 7
```

In addition, in your second version, you need to add `nth_week-1` weeks like you do in your first version.

Complete example:

```
def nth_weekday(the_date, nth_week, week_day):
    temp = the_date.replace(day=1)
    adj = (week_day - temp.weekday()) % 7
    temp += timedelta(days=adj)
    temp += timedelta(weeks=nth_week-1)
    return temp

>>> nth_weekday(datetime(2011,8,9), 3, 4)
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 19, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What result do you get when you run version 2 of my func (corrected as pointed out), with the sample date in my example?. I get **28Sep11** - which is still incorrect. The correct date (easily verifiable) should be `19Aug11`

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: I get the correct value. Make sure you change both `adj` calculation, and `nth_week` -> `nth_week-1`.

Comment: Sorry but this algorithm is wrong - you need to secure that `adj` is always positive (because you are just adding n-1 weeks) - which you can't if you do a subtraction!

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke: The `% 7` will ensure that `adj` is positive.

Comment: @interjay ok - I didn't know that the %-operator works this way - Then your solution is correct of course - Sorry!

Comment: @interjay: Yes I can confirm that the code above does indeed work. I had some previously defined variables polluting my test environment in the console. Thanks for your assistance; much obliged. +1 for a working example and explaining where I was going wrong.

Comment: @Goury Please don't edit other people's code, especially when your version is wrong.

Comment: thanks for this.  saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 9):

**one-liner**

You can find the nth weekday with a one liner that uses calendar from the standard library.

```
import calendar
calendar.Calendar(x).monthdatescalendar(year, month)[n][0]
```

*where:*

- x : the integer representing your weekday (0 is Monday)
- n : the 'nth' part of your question
- year, month : the integers year and month

This will return a datetime.date object.

**broken down**

It can be broken down this way:

```
calendar.Calendar(x)
```

creates a calendar object with weekdays starting on your required weekday.

```
.monthdatescalendar(year, month)
```

returns all the calendar days of that month.

```
[n][0]
```

returns the 0 indexed value of the nth week (the first day of that week, which starts on the xth day).

**why it works**

The reason for starting the week on your required weekday is that by default 0 (Monday) will be used as the first day of the week and if the month starts on a Wednesday, calendar will consider the first week to start on the first occurrence of Monday (ie. week 2) and you'll be a week behind.

**example**

If you were to need the third Saturday of September 2013 (that month's US stock option expiry day), you would use the following:

```
calendar.Calendar(5).monthdatescalendar(2013,9)[3][0]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this high-voted answer is incorrect.  Counter example:  3rd Wednesday in November 2017:  `calendar.Calendar(2).monthdatescalendar(2017,11)[3][0]` returns  datetime.date(2017, 11, 22), whereas the correct value is 2017-11-15

Comment: I concur this is wrong. Try (calendar.Calendar(calendar.SUNDAY).monthdatescalendar(2018, 7)[1][0]) - Gives 2018-07-08 - if you take 7 days off you have 2018-07-01 - so clearly wrong

Comment: If the Calendar(x) indicates very 1st day of a month, it starts from `n/1`. In other cases, 1st row incudes the week day of the last month. You can check this with `calendar.Calendar(1).monthdatescalendar(2020, 12)`.  So this answer needs a bit fix.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the **one-liner** with the most votes is it doesn't work.

It can however be used as a basis for refinement:

You see this is what you get:

```
c = calendar.Calendar(calendar.SUNDAY).monthdatescalendar(2018, 7)
for c2 in c:
    print(c2[0])
```

---

```
2018-07-01
2018-07-08
2018-07-15
2018-07-22
2018-07-29
```

---

```
c = calendar.Calendar(calendar.SUNDAY).monthdatescalendar(2018, 8)
for c2 in c:
    print(c2[0])
```

---

```
2018-07-29
2018-08-05
2018-08-12
2018-08-19
2018-08-26
```

If you think about it it's trying to organise the calendars into nested lists to print a weeks worth of dates at a time. So stragglers from other months come into play. By using a new list of valid days that fall in the month - this does the trick.

---

**Answer with appended list**

```
import calendar
import datetime
def get_nth_DOW_for_YY_MM(dow, yy, mm, nth) -> datetime.date:
    #dow - Python Cal - 6 Sun 0 Mon ...  5 Sat
    #nth is 1 based... -1. is ok for last.
    i = -1 if nth == -1 or nth == 5 else nth -1
    valid_days = []
    for d in calendar.Calendar(dow).monthdatescalendar(yy, mm):
        if d[0].month == mm:
            valid_days.append(d[0])
    return valid_days[i]
```

So here's how it could be called:

```
firstSundayInJuly2018 = get_nth_DOW_for_YY_MM(calendar.SUNDAY, 2018, 7, 1)
firstSundayInAugust2018 = get_nth_DOW_for_YY_MM(calendar.SUNDAY, 2018, 8, 1)
print(firstSundayInJuly2018)
print(firstSundayInAugust2018)
```

And here is the output:

```
2018-07-01 
2018-08-05
```

`get_nth_DOW_for_YY_MM()` can be refactored using lambda expressions like so:

**Answer with lambda expression refactoring**

```
import calendar
import datetime
def get_nth_DOW_for_YY_MM(dow, yy, mm, nth) -> datetime.date:
    #dow - Python Cal - 6 Sun 0 Mon ...  5 Sat
    #nth is 1 based... -1. is ok for last.
    i = -1 if nth in [-1,5] else nth -1
    return list(filter(lambda x: x.month == mm, \
          list(map(lambda x: x[0], \ 
            calendar.Calendar(dow).monthdatescalendar(yy, mm) \
          )) \
        ))[i]
```

---

Answer (score 1):

The one-liner answer does not seem to work if the target day falls on the first of the month. For instance, if you want the 2nd Friday of every month, then the one-liner approach

```
calendar.Calendar(4).monthdatescalendar(year, month)[2][0]
```

for March 2013 will return March 15th 2013 when it should be March 8th 2013. Perhaps add in a check like

```
if date(year, month, 1).weekday() == x:
    delivery_date.append(calendar.Calendar(x).monthdatescalendar(year, month)[n-1][0])
else:
    delivery_date.append(calendar.Calendar(x).monthdatescalendar(year, month)[n][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

The [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) module that's an extension from the [Python dateutil package](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) (`pip install python-dateutil`) does exactly what you want:

```py
from dateutil import relativedelta
import datetime


def nth_weekday(the_date, nth_week, week_day):
    return the_date.replace(day=1) + relativedelta.relativedelta(
        weekday=week_day(nth_week)
    )

print(nth_weekday(datetime.date.today(), 3, relativedelta.FR))
```

The key part here evaluates to `weekday=relativedelta.FR(3)`: the third Friday of the month. Here are the relevant part of the [docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) for the `weekday` parameter,

> weekday:
>
> One of the weekday instances (MO, TU, etc) available in the
> relativedelta module. These instances may receive a parameter N,
> specifying the Nth weekday, which could be positive or negative
> (like MO(+1) or MO(-2)).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively this will work for Python 2, returns the occurance of weekday in the said month, i.e if 16 June 2018 is the input, then returns the occurance of the day on 16th June 2018

You may substitute the month/year/date integers to anything you might want - right now it's getting the input / date from the system via `datetime`

Omit out print statements or use `pass` where they're not needed

```
import calendar
import datetime
import pprint

month_number = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m'))
year_number = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y'))
date_number = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d'))
day_ofweek = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%A'))


def weekday_occurance():
print "\nFinding current date here\n"
for week in xrange(5):
    try:
        calendar.monthcalendar(year_number, month_number)[week].index(date_number)
        occurance = week + 1
        print "Date %s of month %s and year %s is %s #%s in this month." % (date_number,month_number,year_number,day_ofweek,occurance)
        return occurance
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print "The date specified is %s which is week %s" % (e,week)



myocc = weekday_occurance()
print myocc
```

Answer (score 0):

A little tweak would make the one-liner work correctly:

```
import calendar
calendar.Calendar((weekday+1)%7).monthdatescalendar(year, month)[n_th][-1]
```

Here `n_th`  should be interpreted as c-style, e.g. 0 is the first index.

Example: to find 1st Sunday in July 2018 one could type:

```
>>> calendar.Calendar(0).monthdatescalendar(2018, 7)[0][-1]
datetime.date(2018, 7, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

People here seem to like one-liner, I will propose below.

```py
import calendar
[cal[0] for cal in calendar.Calendar(x).monthdatescalendar(year, month) if cal[0].month == month][n]
```

Answer (score 0):

### European (ISO) day format (get nth weekday of the month)

```
def is_nth_weekday(nth: int, isodaynum: int):
    if isodaynum not in range(1, 8):
        raise ValueError('isodaynum should be in [1, 7], for [monday, sunday]')
    daynum = isodaynum - 1

    if date(date.today().year, date.today().month, 1).weekday() == daynum:
        nth = nth - 1
    nth_weekday = calendar.Calendar(daynum).monthdatescalendar(
        date.today().year,
        date.today().month
    )[nth][0]
    return date.today() == nth_weekday
```

For example:

```
# is third Friday of the month (stock options expiration)
is_nth_weekday(nth=3, isodaynum=5)
```

returns `True` only on third Friday of the current month