# Finding the third Thursday of the month in Python

Tags: python, date

I need to determine if today is the third Thursday of the current month. What is an efficient way to accomplish this using Python?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 6):

Following @inegm's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883058/nth-weekday-calculation-in-python-whats-wrong-with-this-code), you can use the `calendar` module to solve your problem:

```
def is_nth_weekday(daynum, nth):
    if date(date.today().year, date.today().month, 1).weekday() == daynum:
        nth = nth - 1
    return date.today() == calendar.Calendar(daynum).monthdatescalendar(
        date.today().year, 
        date.today().month
    )[nth][0]
```

The expression `calendar.Calendar(nth).monthdatescalendar(date.today().year, date.today().month)[daynum][0]` returns a datetime object corresponding to the `nth` occurence of the `daynum` day of the week.  In your case you'd want to call `is_nth_weekday(3, 3)` (because counting from Monday as `0`, Thursday is `3`).

Comment: +1. This solution is clean, uses a default lib, and doesn't rely on magic numbers and is less prone to off-by-one-errors.

Comment: This works well, but I don't understand why we need the `nth = nth - 1` part.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today()
is_third_thurs = today.weekday() == 3 and today.day >= 15 and today.day <= 21
```

Basically, if today is Thursday, and it's not too late or too early for it to be the third Thursday, then today must be the third Thursday.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<= 21`? The 22nd could be the 4th thursday, if my math is not wrong.

Comment: You're right!  I edited the answer, thanks for your correction.

Comment: `is_third_thurs = today.weekday() == 3 and 15 <= today.day <= 21`

Comment: Whaaaaaa?  I didn't know you could do inequalities like that in Python.  Learn something new everyday.  Thanks Padraic